# Traversing a given path on a tree with labelled nodes

Tags: sqlite, tree, recursive-query

Suppose that we have a tree with labelled nodes where each node has a *unique* id and a *non-unique* label.
A path on the tree can be described by an ordered set of labels; eg., with a path descriptor,
`P = ['', 'a', 'a.1', 'a.1.3'] = "/a/a.1/a.1.3"` (similar to a path under Unix).
The goal is to find the node ids which correspond to this path; eg., `P = 1 -> 2 -> 5 -> 8`.

Let’s make a minimal example in SQLite as follows:

```
-- define the nodes
CREATE TABLE nd
    (uid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
     label TEXT);

-- note that some nodes might have similar labels (here, 2 and 9) 
INSERT INTO nd
    VALUES (1, '' ), (4, 'd'),
           (3, 'b'), (9, 'a'),
           (2, 'a'), (5, 'a.1'),
           (6, 'a.1.1'), (7, 'a.1.2'), (8, 'a.1.3');

-- define the tree structure (adjacency list)
CREATE TABLE tr
    (child INTEGER REFERENCES nd (uid),
     parent INTEGER REFERENCES nd (uid));

INSERT INTO tr
    VALUES (1, NULL), (4, 1),
            (3, 1), (9, 3), 
            (2, 1), (5, 2),
            (6, 5), (7, 5), (8, 5);


/* Tree structure (+ indicates a node)

       + 1:root
       |
---------------
|      |      |
+ 4:d  + 3:b  + 2:a
       |      |
       + 9:a  + 5:a.1
              |
       ---------------
       |      |      |
       +      +      +
       8      7      6
     a.1.3  a.1.2  a.1.1
*/
```

One can easily find the direct children of a node with id = 1:

```
SELECT tr.child AS uid, nd.label AS label
    FROM tr
    JOIN nd
    ON tr.child = nd.uid
    WHERE tr.parent = 1;
```

Or find the id of a direct children 'b' of node 1:

```
SELECT tr.child AS uid, nd.label AS label
    FROM tr
    JOIN nd
    ON (tr.parent = 1 AND nd.label = 'b'
        AND tr.child = nd.uid);
```

Now, let’s define a path descriptor, `P = "/a/a.1/a.1.3"`:

```
CREATE TABLE P (label TEXT);
INSERT INTO P VALUES
    (''), ('a'), ('a.1'), ('a.1.3'); -- path 1/2/5/8
```

I made up (or imagined) a recursive query to find the corresponding uids:

```
WITH RECURSIVE
trPath (uid, label, depth) AS (
    -- first (uid, label) from the path descriptor
    SELECT nd.uid, nd.label, 1 FROM nd
    WHERE nd.label = (SELECT label FROM P WHERE P.ROWID = 1)

    UNION ALL

    WITH
    -- next uid from path descriptor (only a single element)
    parentLabel (uid) AS (
    SELECT uid FROM nd
    WHERE nd.label = (SELECT P.label FROM P, trPath WHERE P.ROWID = trPath.depth + 1)
    LIMIT 1
    ),
    -- uids of children of current parent 
    childrenIds (uid) AS (
    SELECT child FROM tr
    WHERE tr.parent = (SELECT uid FROM parentLabel)
    ),
    -- uid, label of children of current parent 
    children (uid, label) AS (
    SELECT chl.uid, nd.label FROM childrenIds
    JOIN nd ON (nd.uid = childrenIds.uid)
    )
    SELECT uid, label, trPath.depth + 1 from children, trPath
)
SELECT * FROM trPath;
```

The result should be a table like

```
uid | label | depth
1|''|1
2|a|2
5|a.1|3
8|a.1.3|4
```

Yet it does not work, since it is indeed not a valid SQLite query.
How should one perform such a query in SQLite?

Answer (score 1):

This works for your sample data (Requires Sqlite 3.25 or newer):

```
WITH RECURSIVE tree AS
  (SELECT child, parent, '' AS label, 1 AS depth FROM tr WHERE parent IS NULL
   UNION ALL
   SELECT tr.child, tr.parent, nd.label, t.depth + 1
   FROM tr
   JOIN tree AS t ON tr.parent = t.child
   JOIN nd ON tr.child = nd.uid)
, path AS (SELECT label, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY label) AS depth FROM p)
SELECT t.child AS uid, t.label, t.depth
FROM tree AS t
JOIN path ON t.label = path.label AND t.depth = path.depth
ORDER BY t.depth;
```

producing

```
uid         label       depth     
----------  ----------  ----------
1                       1         
2           a           2         
5           a.1         3         
8           a.1.3       4
```

---

For best results, create indexes on `P(label)` and `tr(parent, child)` (Or make them primary keys.)

Comment: `tree` reproduces all the paths in the tree?

Comment: `path AS (SELECT label, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY label) AS depth FROM p)` re-numbers the rows of `P`?

Comment: @AlQuemist Have to traverse the tree to calculate the depth of each node -- and the other CTE calculates the depth of each segment of the path.

Comment: I think multiple `JOIN`s is the key here! I found a simpler solution.

Answer (score 0):

With a hint from the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59017194) by @Shawn, I found a simpler answer which does *not* need window functions, and uses multiple `JOIN`s:

```
WITH RECURSIVE
pathT (uid, label, parent, pstr, idx) AS (
    SELECT uid, label, NULL AS parent, CAST(uid AS TEXT) AS pstr, 1 AS idx
    FROM (SELECT * FROM P LIMIT 1) --> take the 1st element of the path descriptor
    JOIN nd USING(label) --> uid of the current label

UNION ALL

    SELECT tr.child, pathT.uid, nd.label,
           pathT.pstr || "/" || CAST(tr.child AS TEXT),
           pathT.idx + 1
    FROM pathT
    JOIN tr ON (pathT.uid = tr.parent) --> uid of a child node
    JOIN nd ON (tr.child = nd.uid) --> label of the child node
    JOIN P  ON (P.label = nd.label) --> label of the child must match that of the current label
    WHERE P.ROWID = pathT.idx + 1 --> take the next element of the path descriptor
)
SELECT * FROM pathT;
```

which yields:

```
1|||1|1
2|1|a|1/2|2
5|2|a.1|1/2/5|3
8|5|a.1.3|1/2/5/8|4
```

Note that this does not need to obtain all paths on the tree (cf. Shawn's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59017194)).

This above query is equivalent to

```
WITH RECURSIVE
pathT (uid, label, parent, pstr, idx) AS (
    SELECT uid, label, NULL AS parent,
           CAST(uid AS TEXT) AS pstr, 1 AS idx
    FROM (SELECT * FROM lP LIMIT 1) --> take the 1st element of the path descriptor
    JOIN nd USING(label) --> uid of the current label

UNION ALL

    SELECT tr.child, pathT.uid, nd.label,
           pathT.pstr || "/" || CAST(tr.child AS TEXT),
           pathT.idx + 1
    FROM pathT, tr, nd, lP
    WHERE pathT.uid = tr.parent --> uid of a child node
      AND tr.child = nd.uid --> label of the child node
      AND lP.label = nd.label --> label of the child must match that of the current label
      AND lP.ROWID = pathT.idx + 1 --> take the next element of the path descriptor
)
SELECT * FROM pathT;
```

where `JOIN`s are replaced by a `WHERE` filter with multiple predicates.

I am still missing in SQL a proper `for`-construct which one finds in functional languages like Scheme, Racket (Lisp) or Haskell, so that one could easily write, for instance:

```
WITH pathT (uid, label, parent, pstr) AS 
FOR P.label FROM P (
    SELECT tr.child, pathT.uid, nd.label,
           pathT.pstr || "/" || CAST(tr.child AS TEXT)
        FROM pathT
        JOIN tr ON (pathT.uid = tr.parent) --> uid of a child node
        JOIN nd ON (tr.child = nd.uid) --> label of the child node
        JOIN P  ON (P.label = nd.label) --> label of the child must match that of the current label
)
SELECT * FROM pathT;
```

without any *explicit* reference to the row indices.